# media query for nexus 10 only?

Tags: css, media-queries, tablet, nexus-10

I'm having trouble specifically targetting the nexus 10 with a media query. It would be simple if I could just do -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0, but I also need it to look good on a Chromebook Pixel, and that dpi is around 220! Setting (min-resolution: 240dpi) does not work :(

Is there any way to target the Nexus 10 Tablet with a media query only?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't target specific devices, you can only create media queries that you expect will cover them. If you consider how many different hiDPI devices there already are available (and how many there will be) it's not practical to try and target individual devices unless you're developing something specific to them such as a presentation.

Having said that, if you're concern is the Chromebook Pixel's DPI is higher than a pixel-ratio: 2.0 and you really want it to look perfect you can use `min-resolution` but the example you've given is targeting a dpi higher than your device.